# I use collision element in my code but still the robot links crush each other. Why?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made a 15 DOF robot and add collision element to avoid internal collisions, but anyway the links collide within each other. I use RViz to visualise the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416794/i-use-collision-element-in-my-code-but-still-the-robot-links-crush-each-other.-why?/) by [TP7](https://answers.ros.org/users/151151/tp7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-06-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2023-06-23**:
Can you able to provide more details? please, If possible upload an image to support questions.

1. What are the steps you have followed till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You misunderstand what the collision element is for: it is used by algorithms for **detecting** collision, but these elements do not directly prevent it. Only some API calls will check for collision and stop the movement. It's your responsibility (or that of the code you chose to run) to not send joint-movement commands that cause collision.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TP7](https://answers.ros.org/users/151151/tp7/) on 2023-06-23**:
Ok thank you for the update